# All features are suspended during recyclerview update

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I need to apply gridlayout to the recyclerview
and draw 1600 items early in the app.
Then I use scrollby to scroll to the location I want.
But it doesn't scroll.
Because app freezes while notifyDataSetChanged is running
And when the items appear in the recyclerview, the stop is released.

Order of execution

-Add Item
-notifyDataSetChanged
-Scroll movement

After creating the test button 
Clicking this button after the update is finished will make scrollby run.

Running notifyDataSetChanged in runOnUiThread also freezes the app for a while. What is the reason?

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mBinding.loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mBinding.horizontalScrollView.scrollBy(((int)((51*movey)*destiny)),0);
                        mBinding.recyclerView.scrollBy(0,((int)((51*movex)*destiny)));
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The stop can be the result of heavy cpu and gpu usage

As a suggestion you can use Paging to show few items per request.